# Remove unknown text usign ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

In my grammar, there are key-value pairs separated by `:`. An example is like this:

```
rule1 : string
rule2 : string
```

I know some directives like `rule1` and `rule2`, and I need to ignore other text (or unknown key-value pairs) found in the file like `rule3`, `randomtext` etc...

In my *ANTLR4* grammar I have the following:

```
group     : rule (comment | rule)* ;
rule      : rule1 | rule2
rule1     : RULE1':' ruleName+ comment* ;
rule2     : RULE2':' ruleName+ comment* ;
ruleName  : ID ID*;
comment   : '#' ID* ;
```

When I test with valid files, all is ok, but when I test for malformed input, like this:

```
rule1: asd
rule2 somestring
```

It detects the first line as correct (as expected), and the second one with and error that say:

> line 2:5 missing ':' at 'somestring'

It is detected as `rule2` parser rule.

The question is, how can I ignore all unknown text from my parser? The unknown rules are the ones that are not contemplated in my parser file.

Thanks